# mysql execution plan less cost with order by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does mysql workbench tell me that:

```
SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 LIMIT 3
```

has a higher cost than:

```
SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 ORDER BY filter2_dec DESC LIMIT 3
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this based on actual run times or estimated cost?

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely because in the order by query you have specified for it to be DESC. This is easier to find because the data is already ordered. Whereas in your other statement, it still has to run through every entry and then limit to the top 3.

The order by is less because you limit after that clause. The data is already ordered so its easier to display a result. Whereas the more costly statement has to do that itself and then limit. This will also be effected by indexes, DBMS and will likely perform differently in an actual live environment.

Comment: I get the same cost for the order by statement when I remove desc.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way MySQL (currently) optimizes `limit`. It basically calculates the query as if there is no limit, and then makes some adjustments to the query plan to acknowledge that it might have an effect.

This will have the side-effect that you cannot really trust the cost value anymore - if you could trust it in the first place: its absolute value has not much meaning, it is just important that it lower than all other execution plans.

**The theory**

First of all, please not that the cost value does not regard the actual number of rows you get. You can e.g. increase the limit value, and it will not change the absolute cost (until it switches to a different execution plan).

Using the index to retrieve 3 rows is obviously a good choice. That is why both queries use that way. But using the (non-covering) index requires a lookup to the table to retrieve the values of the other columns (`select *`). It will read the index, then read one row from the table, then read the next entry from the index, then read the next row from the table. At some point, it obviously becomes faster to just read the whole table ("full table scan") and throw away the rows you do not need instead of using the index.

If you have to order the data, that points comes later than if you do not have to order the data afterwards.

If you do not use a `limit`, MySQL will decide if that point is reached by looking at `filter2_dec > 20` and guessing how many rows it will get. Try to execute your query without a `limit`. It will use a full table scan (otherwise use a lower number than `20`).

Now increase the value `20`, still without limit, to a value high enough so you only get some rows (but more than 0); let's assume that value is `1000`.

Now the tricky part: if you add a `limit`, that point (the value for which it is better to use a range scan instead of a table scan) will obviously change.

MySQL will try to include the effect of that `limit` by doing some modifications in the list of all the possible execution plans that were generated as if there was no limit. E.g. throwing away some of those or add modified copies based on them. This can result in strange values for the cost (as they are not actually the cost for that operation, but of the original plan).

**The practice**

Let's see this in action. As it will depends on the exact optimizer and thus mysql version, so your actual behaviour may vary though. But for this simple query, it should still hold in general. I will assume that `SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20` will use a full table scan, and `SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 1000` will use the index on it own (and will actually return some rows). If not, adjust the value or add more rows (and maybe run an `optimize table`).

First of all, try the following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 
order by filter2_dec 

SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 
order by filter2_dec limit 10
```

should show the same cost for the first step, but it will be a "full table scan" for the first one, and a "index range scan" for the other.

The `limit` basically took the original plan and replaced the "full table scan" with an "index range scan", but it was not able to calculate the new costs. MySQL just "knew" that because of the limit, a full table scan would be ridiculous to use, and changed it to a range scan. The "order by" itself does not cost anything anymore.

Now check the following 3 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 

SELECT * FROM file_results force index (file_results_filter2_dec_index)
WHERE filter2_dec > 20 

SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 20 limit 10
```

The 2nd and the 3rd one should have the same cost, while the first one should be cheaper - but got thrown out by the `limit`-operation, so the 2nd (and 3rd) are now the cheapest way to execute the query (you can take this literally: the `limit` forces you to use the index, as everything else would be just stupid). And finally, this is the reason your query looks more expensive than the other one. It is based on a different plan.

A last check:

```
SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 1000 
order by filter2_dec

SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 1000 
order by filter2_dec limit 10

SELECT * FROM file_results WHERE filter2_dec > 1000 limit 10
```

should all show the same execution plan and identical costs (with or without the limit). That plan will be chosen on its own even without the limit. The adjustments done by the `limit`-optimizer does not need these plans, only plans that were more expensive to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

May be cos filter2_dec got on is structure column a index. But if you need some good analyst i think you have to past the structure about that table the engine using ... Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the following.

In the first query, `filter2_dec > 20` is not very selective.  So, MySQL says:  "I'm going to be selecting lots of rows, so I'll just do a full table scan".  This is probably enhanced by the `LIMIT` because if the values are randomly stored in rows, it will probably hit 3 pretty quickly.  The choice of using the index is rejected based on the selectivity of the `WHERE` clause.

In the second query, the `ORDER BY` keeps the option of using the index as a possibility.  If the engine does a full table scan, then it then needs to sort all the data.  Instead, using the index makes more sense -- and there ends up being an overall savings.

In other words, the selectivity of the `WHERE` clause rejects the use of the index before the cost of the index is considered.  In the second, the option remains open because of the `ORDER BY`.

This is speculation, but it would explain what you are seeing.  Optimizers are hard.

Comment: The execution plan says that it uses an index range scan for both, and not a fullt table scan :(

Comment: @Chris . . . You'll notice that the `ORDER BY` has no cost in the second plan.  What is odd is that the estimate for the range scan differs in the two queries.